# Intellij not finding my Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Since I upgraded IntelliJ to Ultimate 2019.2, I suddenly started having the following problem:

> /opt/jdk-11/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:43359,suspend=y,server=n -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/159/plugins/Groovy/lib/agent/gragent.jar -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/159/plugins/java/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/thomas/workspace/AddyCaddy/out/production/classes:/home/thomas/workspace/AddyCaddy/out/production/resources:/home/thomas/workspace/AddyCaddy/libs/heavyweight-util-1.11.jar:/home/thomas/workspace/AddyCaddy/libs/AddyCaddy-client-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.1.5.RELEASE/4abebc4ec0ee87155bfa8daf6a9d63366308e58a/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.5.RELEASE/f33f69b3744d07f832db6ab48eab227ccde9e922/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/1.5.9/75d4d6e4cdb9a551a102e92a14c640768174e214/mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.5.RELEASE/d46494b46a626cbd8f253066a2d7413412efc908/spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.h2database/h2/1.4.199/7bf08152984ed8859740ae3f97fae6c72771ae45/h2-1.4.199.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.dozer/dozer/5.5.1/f2e52ef54166788ae29b5b4eec6fdb9cd580acab/dozer-5.5.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.1.5.RELEASE/464cfb573009e724ea76ca404f106b1b19e759ff/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.1.5.RELEASE/6f187e708a47b0d37552a01292ce649a97a0059d/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.1.5.RELEASE/82da693e16b112f535e2cb2682a29b23f7378dd0/spring-boot-devtools-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.1.5.RELEASE/cf880b4a4713b2a1aea21f929df718a0260aa29/spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.5.RELEASE/74952d169c2da56f7794b3a88508e52005bb8f36/spring-boot-starter-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.1.5.RELEASE/4e6774d2f4a70e62092dbaace39190f8b1df8083/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.1.4/96eabfe2343a4a4676d215b2122cbbc4d4b6af9b/micrometer-core-1.1.4.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3/e006adf5cf3cca2181d16bd640ecb80148ec0fce/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/8531ad5ac454cc2deb9d4d32c40c4d7451939b5d/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.10.Final/e608b854325005edbf43cb2b6041fdafd3f2eb57/hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.8.RELEASE/385ab53309b4f0dfb317c4753fe853821ff15c08/spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.1.7.RELEASE/15309277b9a18c8dae21272be3e57b69a67c41f6/spring-aspects-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.5.RELEASE/49de1c20ea6b8c6920d0a66329f9bf980e4498eb/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.16.Final/ad9557c558972093c0567a2a1f224f318c00f650/hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.7.RELEASE/686326ff513bf4e852b3ee359cf741d92ab82cfe/spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/5.1.7.RELEASE/595dd528ec66eccc6cf4375ea3b56f3605fa1d1f/spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.1/d2662a4e018671ed061e9acca6299a31b7652f3c/commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/6505a72a097d9270f7a9e7bf42c4238283247755/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.26/33fbc2d93de829fa5e263c5ce97f5eab8f57d53e/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/6c66db1c636ee90beb4c65fe34abd8ba9396bca6/HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/2.1.8.RELEASE/d68b9a9850ee21319469c40bdbdfe4eaaf29557/spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.1.5.RELEASE/b4fe11fb0e606b67b9fb2bd9ae4fe65b484445dd/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.2/6d37bf7b046c0ce2669f26b99365a2cfa45c4c18/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.26/8031352b2bb0a49e67818bf04c027aa92e645d5c/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/77100a62c2e6f04b53977b9f541044d7d722693d/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.5.RELEASE/69ae2819b295603563b95f79abae53f2631c5b94/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.1.5.RELEASE/eccd3c70cfbe9534db19fbdd6cbf86fab884c3c0/spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.1.5.RELEASE/939061a385b4e30e115978d78a7412fb984674df/spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.1.7.RELEASE/b4154d41a70c56eeca42974825fe64a8576642dd/spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.1.7.RELEASE/8138b5e3dd01d514741de35d7f5050599c617509/spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.1.7.RELEASE/1e532795f730814b07961fbf5f14e14bd2507fcd/spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.1.7.RELEASE/d00069664e066c4021fa3de167ad755e4148f340/spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.1.7.RELEASE/d437d5d353312d94206b469b43e203eba1bdcec6/spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.1.7.RELEASE/14cd651e4aa3514e75710c9450c7a0c89413e63f/spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.1.7.RELEASE/7b47446553c83a5a7323d647f5c1793106b2948c/spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.1.7.RELEASE/280f821b9ed4dad9993f1d551d6e86557092ae58/spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/ec62d74fe50689c28c0ff5b35d3aebcaa8b5be68/snakeyaml-1.23.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.8/28ad1bced632ba338e51c825a652f6e11a8e6eac/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.8/bcd02aa9195390e23747ed40bf76be869ad3a2fb/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.8/c4eef0e6e20d60fb27af4bc4770dba7bcc3f6de6/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/11283f21cc480aa86c4df7a0a3243ec508372ed2/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.9/e4631ce165eb400edecfa32e03d3f1be53dee754/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/769c0b82cb2421c8256300e907298a9410a2a3d3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.4/9205229878f3d62fbd3a32a0fb6be2d6ad8589a9/aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.4.Final/965a18fdf939ee75e41f7918532d37b3a8350535/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/25665ac8c0b62f50e6488173233239120fc52c96/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.23.2-GA/c5afe660a95e87ceb518e4f5cf02f5c56b547683/javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.12/39050dbbd36862ea87eb9a64158854b04619ccd6/byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/7060f67764565b9ee9d467e3ed0cb8a9c601b23a/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.4.0/291658ac2ce2476256c7115943652c0accb5c857/classmate-1.4.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.dom4j/dom4j/2.1.1/3dce5dbb3571aa820c677fadd8349bfa8f00c199/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.19/dee79022818f490203f4901f5651f3233aee14db/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.19/56e42e12bf92b713befd0700430f7c5c0af68d49/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.19/6145f2cd11c7df4ad9463637087c0f7e8e673394/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.19.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/761ea405b9b37ced573d2df0d1e3a4e0f9edc668/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.7.RELEASE/6b14bfb9ae41ca1bc604fe2e78f4a6efa3d67002/spring-jcl-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.8/f5a654e4675769c716e5b387830d19b501ca191/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.3/864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/f5e9a2ffca496057d6891a3de65128efc636e26e/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/159/lib/idea_rt.jar org.addycaddy.AddycaddyApplication

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:43359', transport: 'socket'
Error: Could not find or load main class org.addycaddy.AddycaddyApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.addycaddy.AddycaddyApplication
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:43359', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am running this by clicking the play button on the main function of `org.addycaddy.AddycaddyApplication`. I have had to remark the directory as the sources directory and the test sources as well. I re-imported my gradle.build. I tried rebuilding the project but it can't find items in my sources project either.

I also tried invalidating caches and restarting. No change.

I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: First close the Intellij Idea, go to the directory and delete the directory called .idea and delete the file .iml. Then go to File > New > Project from existing sources, import the project as either maven or gradle .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First close the Intellij Idea, go to the directory containing the source code and delete the directory called .idea and delete the file .iml. Then go to **File > New > Project from existing sources**, import the project as either maven or gradle. I provide below the screen shot below.

[image]

Then select the directory and import as either maven or gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a similar problem. I am using Intellij IDEA 2021.2 and some artifacts were not found within pom.xml. I closed the project and re-opened, updated the dependencies via maven and then eeverything was good...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).